# Get the name and link file based on Folder ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I created a script to get the name and link file based on Folder ID. The file name and link are displayed on sheet 'Get_Link'.
[image]
[File spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GcN4p1PktgYX7PjjQq5tJi-KeQTajurBUHtqHt6JHZc/edit#gid=381480960)

The script that I wrote like this:

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Get_Link');
//sheet.appendRow(["File Name","URL"]);

var folderID = [];
folderID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
                         .getRange('Folder_ID!A2:B')
                         .getValues()
                         .reduce(function(p, c) {
                           if (c[0] !== '' && c[1] !== '') {
                                p.push( DriveApp.getFolderById(c[1]).getFiles() );
                                return p; }
                          }, []);

//var searchTerm = Browser.inputBox("Masukkan Folder ID:");
//var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(searchTerm);
//var contents = folder.getFiles();

var cnt = 0;
var file;

while (folderID.hasNext()) {
    var file = folderID.next();
    cnt++;

       data = [
            file.getName(),
            file.getUrl(),
        ];

        sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
};
```

But having an error, 
[image]
how about the correct script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following modifications? I think that there are 2 modification points in your script.

#### Modification points:

- Reason of your error is that `folderID` becomes `undefined`.
- When `folderID` has values, an error occurs at `while (folderID.hasNext()) {`. Because `folderID` is an array.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
.reduce(function(p, c) {
  if (c[0] !== '' && c[1] !== '') {
       p.push( DriveApp.getFolderById(c[1]).getFiles() );
       return p; }
 }, []);
```

#### To:

```
.reduce(function(p, c) {
  if (c[0] !== '' && c[1] !== '') {
    p.push( DriveApp.getFolderById(c[1]).getFiles() );
  }
  return p; // Modified
}, []);
```

and

#### From:

```
while (folderID.hasNext()) {
    var file = folderID.next();
    cnt++;

       data = [
            file.getName(),
            file.getUrl(),
        ];

        sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
};
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < folderID.length; i++) { // Added
  while (folderID[i].hasNext()) { // Modified
    var file = folderID[i].next(); // Modified
    cnt++;
    var data = [
      file.getName(),
      file.getUrl(),
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: sorry, someone has edited the code

Comment: the code I wrote is right in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try your code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.